# Number of automorphisms satisfying a condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $E/K$ be a Galois extension, $K\subseteq L\subseteq E$ be an intermediate field and $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$. How many elements $\tau \in\mathrm{Gal}(E/K)$ satisfy the relation $\tau|_L=\sigma$?

$E$ is the splitting field of a certain polynomial $f\in L[x]$ over $L$. If $f$ were irreducible over $L$, there would be as many extensions of $\sigma$ as roots of $f$. But this is not true in general.

You can consider the factors $f=p_1\dots p_n$ where $\forall i\in\{1,\dots, n\}, p_i\in L[x]$ is irreducible, and let $L_i$ be the splitting field of $p_i$ over $L$. Then, there are $\delta(p_i)$ extensions of $\sigma$ to $L_i$. I don't know how could I combine these automorphisms to form automorphisms of $E$.

Comment: I guess you're not supposing that $L/K$ is Galois?

Comment: No, the question doesn't say anything about $L/K$. I supposed $E/L$ is Galois because $E/K$ is Galois. But $L/K$ might not be Galois.

Answer (score 0):

I already found an answer. I'll prove inductively that the answer is $|E:L|$.

$E/K$ is Galois, so $E/L$ is Galois as well. Then $E=L(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $E/L$ is normal, and thus finite and algebraic.

If n=1, $E=L(a)$, $a$ algebraic, and then you take $p:=\textrm{Irr}(a,L)$. There are as many extensions of $\sigma$ from $L$ to $E$ as there are roots of $p$ in $E$. But $a$ is a root of $p$ in $E$, and $E$ is a splitting field, so $p$ splits in $E$. This means there are $\delta(p)=|E:L|$ roots of $p$ in $E$ (all of them different given that $p\in L[x]$ is irreducible). The conclusion is that there are $|E:L|$ extensions of $\sigma$ to $E$.

Suppose the proposition is true for $n-1$. Let $E=L(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, $F:=L(a_1,\dots, a_{n-1})$. Then there are $|F:L|$ extensios of  $\sigma$ to $F$. For each one of these extensions, there are $|E:F|$ extensions to $E$. This means there are $|E:F||F:L|=|E:L|$ extensions of $\sigma$ from $L$ to $E$.